# let Tycho/Jenkins build fail when p2 site doesn't exist

Tags: jenkins, tycho

I have an RCP application which I build in Jenkins using "mvn clean verify" to run Maven/Tycho. When the target platform of my application contains a p2 repository site that is not available anymore, Tycho prints a warning but still uses it's local cache.

```
[WARNING] Failed to access p2 repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.11.1/indigo, use local cache. Neither http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.11.1/indigo/content.jar nor http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.11.1/indigo/content.xml found.
```

It took my quite some time to notice this problem because the Jenkins build succeeds without any issues and I am not going to read all console output...

I would like to get notified of this issue so I can take measures when a repository is moved or deleted. Tycho should still use it's cache under normal circumstances.

Can I solve this using Jenkins or can I instruct Tycho to fail fast (drawback: also fails on temporary outage)?

To partly answer my question the best solution is probably to set up a local p2 mirror, but I think this requires a lot more work.

Comment: I could use the Jenkins Text finder plugin and mark the build unstable if the text 'Failed to access p2 repository' is present. Not sure if this is the cleanest solution? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin

Comment: My apologies, this question does not satisfy Stackoverflow standards. I started out asking a specific question about Tycho only and only then realized my original problem is better solved using Jenkins.

Comment: It has been agreed on that the current behaviour is not good and that Tycho should rather fail fast if a repository is not available. However this has not been implemented yet. See [Tycho bug 410698](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=410698) for details and the current status.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark a Jenkins build unstable or failed based on it's output by using the Jenkins Text finder plugin.

- Manage Jenkins plugins and install the text finder plugin from the
  Available plugins.
- Edit the project to add a post-build action "Jenkins Text Finder".
- Check 'Also search the console output', set the Regular expression to
  'Failed to access p2 repository' and check 'Unstable if found'.